# How to respond to an SMS message from user and store content from their message in my database?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am new to the salesforce marketing API and want to know how to respond to a text message from a user and store information they send in my database. Should I be using SMS interactions or Mobile Connect?

Is there a code example somewhere of what needs to be set up?

Additionally, how might I respond to a picture message/store the picture?

Thank you very much for your time. I am still researching, let me know if you need more info or I am being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're after can be found here: [AMPScript Variables for Use with Mobile Messages](https://web.archive.org/web/20151214145657/http://help.exacttarget.com:80/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/)

With the message components as variables, you can write values to a Data Extension, including the URL of the image. Theoretically, you could use AMPScript to download and move this to the Portfolio.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking into this and AMPScripts. I have never used AMPScript, do you think it is able to use it to upload the image to Amazon S3 storage?